# Quit app when pressing home 

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, multitasking

I my testing, when I exit (by pressing the home button) my app, it still is "running" in the background, thanks to the multitasking feature.  However, I would like it to quit when the home button is pressed.  Is this only happening to me?

Anyway, I have tracked it down to the `applicationWillResignActive` and the `applicationDidBecomeActive` methods in the app delegate.  These get called for multitasking, but when I want to terminate, the app "resigns active."  Any guidance on this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What would you like to accomplish by quitting your app?

Comment: It's not really "running" in the background, it is suspended, unless you take steps to keep it running (like playing audio).  It doesn't cost anything to keep it suspended and it's faster to switch back to it next time the user runs your app.

Comment: Another question posted to SO before reading the documentation. Perhaps you should ask Apple for an enhancement to Xcode to embed SO in the IDE.

Comment: @falcon I thought with apple you just push a button and its done?  You have to read manuals?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your application can opt out of multitasking (see the [appropriate section](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW24) in the iPhone Application Programming Guide) by adding the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key to your Info.plist and setting its value to YES.

In practice, Apple strongly recommends you not do this unless you have a very good reason for this behavior.

Comment: You should consider whether or not doing this will annoy your users.  They will probably expect that your app remembers where they were, and circumventing this behavior might make them think your app is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more efficient to suspend an app, when pressing the "Home" button. There's overhead in constantly launching and terminating apps. It's worse for the iOS operating system, and it's worse for user experience - because they need to wait for the app to launch again. Not sure what benefits you gain from terminating an app. If it's for simulation testing, my advice is to avoid that functionality, because your testing environment should be as realistic as possible. If your purpose is to clear cache or to make updates - that can all be done programmatically from subroutines.

**Exiting subroutines**

- applicationWillResignActive
- applicationDidEnterBackground
- applicationWillTerminate

**Entering subroutines**

- applicationDidBecomeActive
- applicationWillEnterForeground
- applicatonDidFinishLaunching

If you still insist on terminating an app when the user presses the "Home" button, despite the costs mentioned above - then set the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to true in your Info.plist as suggested by Brad Larson.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't recommend trying to control the user's HOME button... deciding for them "exit" or "suspend".

I *WOULD* like to have HOME do an instant EXIT in the iPhone simulator... but haven't found any way to do that.

Comment: I set the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key during development, and then unset it before doing final testing and release.