# iphone avoid save state

Tags: iphone

In my app I need to avoid the saving state, in fact, I whis that each time the user starts the app, the app will be relaunced like the first time...
how can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone 4 app doesn't terminate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154491/iphone-4-app-doesnt-terminate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `YES` (Boolean) in your Info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do a thing. iOS does nothing to save the state of your app.

Comment: it's strange, I created a new app and when I relaunch the app for the 2nd time, the app appears with the latest view shown..

Comment: It does, starting from 4.0. Technically, it doesn't *save* the app's state but freezes it in memory. The net effect is your app (given it doesn't get killed) resumes where it was left off the last time.

Comment: @ghiboz: it is. see my answer.

Comment: Also, see this blog post by Dr. Touch for more information: http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/

Comment: @ghiboz - It's highly recommended that you allow your application to work with iOS 4.0's multitasking.  You need a very good reason why your application would need to start over at the beginning every time, because that provides a poor user experience.  If possible, figure out a way to make your application work with multitasking.