# quit app in iOS4

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have an old app which did many UI initialization work in viewDidLoad of various views. In iOS4 home button just put the app in background so viewDidLoad won't get called when re-launching the app.

I don't want to put those initialization procedures in viewWillAppear as it is unnecessary to re-initialize the data every time the view appear.

How can I completely quit my app when user press the home button? or any simple way to reload the view controllers that sit inside a tabBarController?

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone avoid save state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227736/iphone-avoid-save-state)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quit app when pressing home](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154491/quit-app-when-pressing-home)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a key in your app's `Info.plist` file called [`UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW23), set it to the boolean `YES`, which will essentially revert the home button's functionality to pre-iOS4 and completely exit your app when the home button is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling backgrounding. Apple has this in their documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try to check.
[UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html)

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

you have to look up to the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification i think, but in the uiapplicationdelegate-protocol, there are even some other interesting things for you

or perfectly for you:
UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification as a new notification in ios4 for this problem