# How to kill my app from multitasking using code in iphone?

Tags: iphone, multitasking, kill

I am looking for a way to kill my app (using code) with a UIbutton and do not keep it on multitasking.
I have tried :
- exit(0);
- applicationWillTerminate

but these 2 methods kill the app but don't stop it from multitasking.

Comment: @Yasmin, I urge you to be more brief and be clear in what you are asking...Providing some code samples and giving examples, will make it easy for answering

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to programmatically remove your application from the task bar, also please note that if you use any of the methods you wrote in your answer, your application will be rejected by apple

Comment: To the OP: remember that the task bar is a "Most Recently Used" list. Even if you crash or programmatically quit your app, it will stay on the list until removed. The coverse is not true: manually removing an app from the list effectively terminates it if it is backgrounded.

Answer (score 1):

Omar's answer is right (so +1 for him for being faster than me, as usual).  You're supposed to give the user the control of deciding when to kill your application and not kill the application yourself.

There is one way to quit the app that appears to work, which is to add the ["`UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`" key](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) to your app's Info.plist file.  When the user puts the app into the background (i.e. home button or incoming call), the app will quit.  More information is available in this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421400/quit-app-in-ios4).  Hope this helps!