# iPhone app remembers last state (multitasking?) unwanted behavior!

Tags: iphone, ios4

User launches the app, quits, relaunches and the app shows up in the exact previous state, as if the app didn't quit at all. I have no custom save state support, so this is really baffling. It happens on one of the user's 3GS, but not on my 3G. Which seems to indicate that this is OS4's multitasking at work, because 3G isn't supported. If this is true, is there a way to turn off this behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone 4 app doesn't terminate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154491/iphone-4-app-doesnt-terminate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, if your app isn’t supposed to use multitasking at all or if you simply wish to disable it during development or debugging, all you’ve to do is to edit your project’s info.plist and depending on how you’re editing it:

```
* Raw text editor
  Add a property named “UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend” and set it’s value to ‘Yes’
* The XCode GUI plist editor
  Add a new row and select “Application does not run in background” (or type “UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend”) and then toggle the checkbox
```

http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/?p=545