# How to exit app while enter background

Tags: ios

I need to exit my app while my app enter into background

Comment: Insufficient detail. Note that Xcode is just an IDE - we need to know what programming language you are using and what OS you are targetting, at the very least.

Comment: You still need more detail. What are you trying to do? Why do you want to do it? What have you tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone 4 app doesn't terminate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154491/iphone-4-app-doesnt-terminate)

Answer (score 17):

If you never want your app to enter the background set the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key in your application’s `Info.plist` file to `YES`

[Opting Out of Background Execution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW24)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to close your iPhone/iPad app when the application is entering into the background :

In `applicationWillEnterBackground` of your app delegate you can do `[[NSThread mainThread] exit]` or `exit(0)`

Comment: Apple specifically recommends against this, because it acts like a crash.  Jason's suggestion of using the UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend property list key is a much better way of handling this.  In any case, exiting on going to the background is recommended against in all but a few cases.

Comment: To me it looks like -[NSThread exit] does not exist.

Comment: can we set a specific time beforing executing the command kill / exit app. In my expeirence if you run it with a timer or DispatchQueue that code doesnt execute